# How to use "__beginthreadex" correctly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++

I am using VC2010, and write following code to test "__beginthreadex"

```
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>

unsigned int __stdcall threadproc(void* lparam)
{
    std::cout << "my thread" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned  uiThread1ID = 0;
    uintptr_t th = _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, threadproc, NULL, 0, &uiThread1ID);

    return 0;
}
```

But nothing is printed to the console. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I added a C++ language tag to this.  Correct if it is something else.

Answer (score 5):

Your main routine exits right away, causing the entire process to shutdown immediately, including all threads that are a part of the process. Its doubtful your new thread even had a chance to begin execution.

The typical way to handle this is to use [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and block until the thread is complete.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned  uiThread1ID = 0;
    uintptr_t th = _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, threadproc, NULL, 0, &uiThread1ID);

    // block until threadproc done
    WaitForSingleObject(th, INFINITE/*optional timeout, in ms*/);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some programmers don't bother with waiting on some working threads, but that is a mistake that programmers cover up by hiding exceptions in working threads. All threads must end before main thread ends.

Comment: @Dialecticus: [it's not that simple](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/27/10054832.aspx)

Comment: I think you misunderstood me because I cut the line short. I meant to say that programmer must make sure that all worker threads end before main thread ends.